# fetching data from a database in realtime, with ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, jquery

I am fetching data from the following database:

[image]

I have arduino-box that send that data.

And display the data with this CSS & HTML code:

```
    <div class="event">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/80x70/f00/fff.png" alt="picture" />  
        <p>Room 2</p>
        <p class="patient-name">Jon Harris</p>
        <p class="event-text">This is a pixel. A flying pixel!</p>
        <p class="event-timestamp">feb 2 2011 - 23:01</p>
    </div>

.event {  
    display:block;  
    background: #ececec;  
    width:380px;  
    padding:10px;  
    margin:10px;  
    overflow:hidden;  
    text-align: left;
}  
.event img {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}  

.event p {  
    font-weight: bold;
}

.event img + p {
    display:inline;
}

.patient-name {
    display:inline;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height:inherit;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.event-text{
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.event-timestamp{
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>DASHBOARD - Arduino 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","***");
        if(!con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events");
        //Start container
        echo " <div id='background_container'> ";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<div class='event'>";
            echo "<img src='img/ev_img/red.jpg' alt='picture' />";
            echo "<p>" . $row['inneboende'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='patient-name'>" . "$row['overvakare']" . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='event-text'>" . "$row['handelse']" . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='event-timestamp'>" . "$row['tid']" . "</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

        //end container
        echo "</div>"
        mysql_close($con);

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The arduino box is sending data to the database.. lets say every 3sec. I dont want to press F5 every 5sec to get the new data. Should I use AJAX for this? I have read some AJAX on the net, but I haven´t find any good tuts for it.

Comment: @Ascherer I dont know, please upvote this question i you find it useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in a separate php file, e.g. getEvents.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","***");
    if(!con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("arduino_db",$con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<div class='event'>";
        echo "<img src='img/ev_img/red.jpg' alt='picture' />";
        echo "<p>" . $row['inneboende'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class='patient-name'>" . "$row['overvakare']" . "</p>";
        echo "<p class='event-text'>" . "$row['handelse']" . "</p>";
        echo "<p class='event-timestamp'>" . "$row['tid']" . "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    mysql_close($con);
```

Then, load jquery and put the following in the head of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $.get('getEvents.php', function (data) {
            $('#background_container').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

*Note: This is not the exact code you should use, take a look at it and change it so it works correctly for you.*

Comment: Thanks, I have an idea how to build it.. I found a useful tip here to: http://bit.ly/mQlsPT

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to refresh the page every 5 seconds, you should use javascript and look at setTimeout:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",5000);
```

5000 is equal to 5 seconds.

Comment: You can still use that only make the first argument an ajax function.